# How to format SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, themes

Hi is there anyway to format ssrs tablix? I mean, I would like to apply some styles, themes similer to charts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but if you are designing multiple reports it is going to be a pain to do this to EVERY SINGLE Tablix by hand.
Why not define some colors in the code section and set the expression for whatever you are trying to spruce up to that entry?
Example: Set in code `Public Const TablixHeaderBGColor As String = "#b5121b"`
Then set `BackgroundColor` to `=Code.TablixHeaderBGColor`
Declare as many as you need and then you only have to change them in one spot to change all Tablix styles.
I took this a step further and put entries in a Database and now ALL my reports styles can be changed in one spot using hex or html color names.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an Old Question.  but I did find a way to insert Tablix's with a Theme. 
there are only 6 options, but I am sure you can download more from somewhere.

if use the Table Wizard it will give you 6 options for designing the Table. unfortunately after you are finished with the wizard there is no way to change the entire style in one step. instead you have to change the properties for each TextBox in the Table.
I hope this helps. I will keep looking for more ways to change the style of the report overall, if I find anything I will Edit my Post.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Insert a Tablix control into your Report Designer, hit F4, and change the properties of the Tablix element (Borders, Fonts, Padding, Size, etc.) at will.